# PHP can't create file, permission denied

Tags: php, apache, permissions, centos

I am trying to run some PHP applications on CentOS powered server with apache and MySQL. My apps have to create files on server, but it always says that permission is denied to create a file.

Files are located in `/var/www/html`. I even tried setting `777` permission to html folder and `html/*`. I changed apache user and group to myuser, that exists, and restarted apache. I changed the ownership of html folder and all files inside to myuser. I even tried changing document root to `/home/myuser/public_html`

I tried this code to test write permission. File location is `/var/www/html/index.php` and `/home/myuser/public_html/index.php`

```
$handle = fopen("a.txt", "w");
fwrite($handle, "test");
fclose($handle);
```

I am just more than amazed by this problem. The same configuration works on my another Ubuntu server.

Some geniuses must be here, help me.

Comment: You do understand that settings permissions to `777` is very bad practice, right?

Comment: Check your directory permission it should be like www-data

Comment: check the permission of file a.txt

Comment: Omi, a.txt doesn't exist, the script has to create.

Comment: Venkat Lokeswar, apache's user and group has been changed to mysuer and myuser, so it might not make any sense.

Comment: @DipakAcharya check the permission of directory where you are going to create file

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow you server user to do write operation on your directory, User the below command, If it is a multilevel directory use -R flag.

```
sudo chown www-data my-dir
```

Comment: Apache user has been chaned to myuser and public_html directory is owned by myuser.

Comment: Usually we will give the permissions to the entire project directory

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually giving permission you can try `chmod($handle, 0777)` within your code.